# Is it possible to download a Teams meeting recording without access to its chat?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to download a teams meeting recording without using the graphical Teams application. The meeting event was created using the [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint, with parameters to make it an online meeting.

Unlike meetings created with the [create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint, these do not have a direct endpoint to get the recording. After extensive research, I learned from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/746161/how-to-downloaded-recorded-calls-meeting-directly) that to download recordings we need to go through the meeting chat and find the recording link in there. With the link, we can then download it.

However, to access chats we need advanced [Protected APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis), which are a hassle. So is there another way to download these meeting recordings?

Answer (score 0):

Use GET `/chats/{chat-id}/messages/{message-id}` to get callRecordingDisplayName.

Next use the Below API to download the meeting recordings.

```
GET /users/{user-id}/drive/root:/Recordings/{callRecordingDisplayName}:/content
```

Please refer to a similar post [How to downloaded recorded calls/meeting directly through Microsoft Teams Graph API?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/746161/how-to-downloaded-recorded-calls-meeting-directly)

Comment: I don't know which message contains the link, so I can't do a GET request on it. First I have to list all the messages and later search for the link, right? Please correct me if I am missing something here.

Comment: If you have particular chat id and message id then you will get the details-
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X85wW.png

If you don't have the id, then you can use the below Api and search the "CallRecordingUrl"
Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example